# SQL Server: stored procedure related

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two input parameters `shopid` and `categoryid`

I want to create a stored procedure for `categoryproductlist` for displaying products related to `categoryid`. I have a table `product` with columns `productid , shopid , title` and I have a table `category` with columns `shopid,title,logical code, categoryid`

Can anyone tell me how to write a stored procedure for `categoryproductlist` with these input parameters?

Comment: I am new to stored procedures

Comment: Which database are you using - SQL server from the title? If you can write the select statement then you can easily turn that into a stored procedure or function - can you write a select for this?

Comment: You'll need to add a CategoryID column to your Products table, unless you're relating them by ShopID.  Otherwise it'll be assumed that all products will be in all categories.

Comment: I have another table called tblcategoryproduct with columns  categoryproductid , categoryid , productid

Comment: pls help me i am really confused for writing this stored procedure

Comment: what is the purpose of the `shopId` parameter? do you need to filter the results based on the `shopId`? is it superfluous?

Comment: Hi - for future reference there's an edit link by the question you can use to add extra information like your tblcategoryproduct to the question itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a go at this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_CategoryProductList
    @CategoryID INT
    @ShopID     INT

AS

SELECT
    c.itle as CategoryTitle,
    c.[logical code],
    p.title as ProductTitle
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN tblcategoryproduct cp on p.ProductID=cp.ProductID
INNER JOIN Category c on c.CategoryID=cp.CategoryID
WHERE c.ShopID=@ShopID
AND   c.CategoryID=@CategoryID
```

Comment: I wouldn't ever use `SELECT * ` in a stored procedure - spell out the columns you're returning - less nasty surprises that way!!

Comment: @marc_s Right, thanks. I just threw that in there quick and forgot to update.  I'll fix.